# How to listen the checkbox checked in andorid?

Tags: android, android-checkbox

what differences between the `setOnClickListener(...)` and the `setOnCheckedChangeListener()` int `checkbox`? And how can i listen the state changed?

Comment: Have you checked the documentation for both methods?

Comment: sorry , it's  not asked in detail. when i click the checkbox, how can i stop the state to change, it nends to show a dialog , when i agree, the checked state can change , when i choose no , the checkbox don't change.

Answer (score 0):

> ... setOnCheckedChangeListener()... And how can i listen the state changed?

You pretty much answered your own question: use `setOnCheckedChangeListener()` to be notified for checked state changes.

Answer (score 0):

"On checked change" fires when the state changes, which could be due to user clicking, or because your program marks the checkbox as checked. The click listener fires only when the user clicks on the checkbox. Depending on what you need you may need to use one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

All of View (textView, imageView, editText ,etc.) have some similar attribute like onClickListener. but every item has their own specific attribute too.

for example CheckBox has onCheckChangeListener or editText has onTextChangeListener.

Answer (score 0):

With OnCheckedChangeListener you receive an event whenever the checked status changes, even when done in code by using .setChecked().

Depending on what you are doing this can lead to unexpected behavior (for example when you have a checkbox in a listview, the view is recycled and the checkbox state is modified programmatically, it looks exactly the same way as if the user had clicked it).

Therefore, when you are writing code that is supposed to react to a user who clicked the checkbox you should use OnClickListener.

Comment: it means that, when i click the checkbox, the checked state must have a change, the onClick() can lead to setChecked(), but the setChecked() don't lead to the  onClick().How can i control the click, when i click, the checkbox don't change immediately, but when i agree(such as show a dialog) the checked state can change. Sorry for my poor english. Thx.

Answer (score -1):

I have an idea, when i click the CheckBox, the state of CheckBox can maintain the original state.

```
mCheckBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mCheckBox.setChecked(mCheckBox.isChecked());
        }
    });
```

Comment: This is useless. You are setting the state of the `CheckBox` to the state of the `CheckBox`. This accomplishes nothing.

Comment: @DavidWasser this is just to maintain the original state, i had say it.

Comment: This code does nothing. The original state isn't maintained or changed by this code.